# intransitive verbs as past participle form without' have'

Tags: past-participles

She is gone.

'Go' is an intransitive verb, but it is used as the past participle form without 'have'. What are other verbs, if any, used like this?

Comment: Gone is more like an adjective that was formed from the participle.

Comment: "Gone" is a past-participial adjective meaning that she is in the state resulting from having gone or departed. Other past-participial adjectives include "distressed", "broken" and "retired".

Comment: thank you all. I'll note them as adjectives, then. but I knew this, too. I just wanted to know if there were some commonalities between the principal adjectives. thanks, anyway ^^.

Answer (score 1):

> She is gone.

*Gone* here means that she is no more or no longer present. Here “gone” is used as an adjective and not as a verb.

Verbs can become adjectives by turning into participles, like in the following examples:

1. He is **done** with you.
2. My heart is **broken**.

Here both “gone” and “done” are used as adjectives.

Comment: You need to be careful with the terminology. Present participles and past participles are verbs. "Done" in the OP's example is not a participle; it's a past-participial adjective (or just participial adjective).